# Added a try and catch function to a method and get an exception for [DataRow] or [DynamicData]?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Ok I have a method to login to the website using selenium and c# called LoginAndSelectAutomationFleet but when I run it I get an exception:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.ObjectModel.TestFailedException: Only data driven test methods can have parameters. Did you intend to use [DataRow] or [DynamicData]?
```

All I have done is convert the method into a test method with a try and catch.  Here is the code:

```
[TestMethod]
 public void LoginAndSelectAutomationFleet(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            // login the user
            _userSetRepo = new UserSetttingsRep(driver);
            _regRep = new UserRegRep(driver);
            objCommon = new clsCommon(driver);
            objCommon.loginVT(driver);
            string getTitle = driver.Title;
            try
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(getTitle == "Amazing Power");
                Console.WriteLine("The application " + getTitle + " has logged in successfully!");


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("The user failed to log in successfully!");
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[text()='User']"))).Click(); 


            WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            wait1.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//a[@class='vt-navbar__child-menu-link']//input")));

            objCommon.SendKeysAndClickTab(_userSetRepo.inputOrgansiation, "Companyxyz", driver);
}
```

How to resolve ?

Answer (score 0):

**A test method must meet the following requirements:**

- It's decorated with the [TestMethod] attribute.
- It returns void.
- It cannot have parameters.

[As per documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-managed-code?view=vs-2019)

Your best solution would be to get `IWebDriver driver` from a method called within the `[TestMethod]` or by having `IWebDriver driver` as a global variable. For example:

```
[TestMethod]
 public void LoginAndSelectAutomationFleet()
 {
     IWebDriver driver = someMethod() //Returns an IWebDriver that you need.
 }
```

Comment: Don't understand I already pass through IWebDriver driver as a parameter? I also have IWebDriver driver already set as a global variable

Comment: Right, you're passing `IWebDriver driver` as a parameter, you can't do that with a `[TestMethod]`. Take it out of your method declaration and put it in the body either by accessing it via global scope or via another method that returns your driver.